# Reference to event from outer scope. Event null c#

Tags: c#, events

I want in use the `event.Invoke()` in a method that takes an action as an argument.

So this is my event code:

```
private event MyEvent _onMyEvent;
public event MyEvent onMyEvent { //only one subscriptor
        add {
            if (_onMyEvent == null) {
                _onMyEvent += value;
                Debug.LogError($"_onMyEvent null1: {_onMyEvent.IsNull()}");
            }
        }
        remove {
            _onMyEvent -= value;
        }
    }
```

public delegate void MyEvent ();

When method subscription takes part in another class with the += the add() is called, and when the subsciption takes place the debug error sys that the event is not null (see the debugError from unity).

So I have this other method in a differente class, `HandlerClass`:

```
public void ActionExecute(Action methodToExecute)
{
    //meaningful code
}
```

When I try to pass in the event to invoke the suscribed methods with the Execute method, it is imposible, because the event is null.
The event is null, although in the assignation it wasnt, and the event is a class variable

```
HandlerClassInstance.ActionExecute( () => {_onMyEvent.Invoke(); });
```

I imagined is was a scope issue as there are issues passing events around, so I tried inlining an action and pass it to the lambda:

```
var myAction = new Action<MyEvent>(delegate (MyEvent event) {
    event.Invoke();
}
HandlerClassInstance.ActionExecute( myAction(_onMyEvent)});
```

And making a class method that would hand the class variable itself:

```
private void invoke() { //this is a class method on the _onMyEvent holding class, so I thought here the problem would be gone.
    Debug.LogError($"_onMyEventnull2: {_onMyEvent.IsNull()}");
    _onMyEvent.Invoke();
}
HandlerClassInstance.ActionExecute(() => invoke());
```

In all the cases I am getting that the event is not null in the assignation, but the it is when called from the HandlerClass.ActionExecute().

The HandlerClass.ActionExecute() dequeues this subscribed methods that are Invoked() from there, but I dont understad why the event reference is lost, or how to pass that through.

I read its not possible to pass event references around. What can be done then to call the Invoke() of an event that is in an outer scope as in my problem. Is this possible?

Comment: events can only be invoked by the class that owns them. That's the whole point of events. external code can subscribe to them, but only the owner can invoke them. If you want to be able to arbitrarily invoke a delegate, then just use a delegate rather than an event.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I need to hold the delegate that is a method from another class at a determined time (subscribing to the event) and execute it at a determined time(.Invoke()). That was why I approched the problem with an event. Any comments on how to approach that without using event would be much appreciated

Comment: An event is just a delegate with some special restrictions. Just remove the `event` keyword, and pass around your `MyEvent` delegate. You can call `onMyEvent()` or `onMyEvent.Invoke()` (same thing) anywhere at any time.

Comment: Ok I will try that out. My problem is that where I would do the event subscription (the +=), I can set the delegate, but cannot pass the arguments through, and I need those to call the delegate with its arguments to be called from the other class. I will try to figure that out